# How would I write a regular expression to extract vertically printed months from a financial report

Tags: regex

I have numerous text based financial reports that I ultimately want to convert to a CSV file.  The file includes three columns with three-letter month abbreviations that are printed vertically.  The vertical months (JAN FEB, ...) conspire to disrupt the flow of the financial report and I would like to remove them from the file in the first round of a process aimed ultimately at extracting the financial data.  I have included an image of what I'm describing below:

[image]

EDIT: I do know that the months are always in Capital Letters.

As you can see, the Sales line is running into C in the DEC in the third row.  A couple rows down you can see that Gross Margin is between the 2nd and 3rd Ns in November.  So the question is how can I write some regular expressions that remove the Dates from the document and then extract my financial data.

EDIT 2: Here is a paste of more of the file:

```
D                             D                             D
E                             E                             E
C                             C   Sales $123,000C

Cost of Goods Sold $120,000


N                             NGross Margin $3,000N
O                             O                             O
V                             V      20-          OperatingV




O                             O                             O
C                             C       30,000       TravelC
T                             T                             T




S                             S       120          UtilitiesS
E                             E                             E
P                             P                             P


10,000 Membership
A                             A                             A
U                             U                             U
G                             G      1,9000              RentG


26          Postage

J                             J                             J
L                             L                             L
Y                             Y                             Y
2,400            Tooling


J                             J                             J
U                             U                             U
N    -22,000             Taxes                             NPretax Income
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the `20-   vu20AQDGnV` about? Could you possibly paste the data verbatim - rather than using a picture?

Comment: Agreed. That weird vu20AQDGn segment could make this...bothersome. The rest is not so bad.

Comment: Thanks for pasting data. (i) Do you require a single expression to do all the work, or are two to three passes acceptable? (ii) The very last line has just two `N`.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor, did my answer work? If so, please select it so this question is no longer in the Unanswered category of the regex tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your pattern to find for all those offending letters using the Test data you provided.

```
((^[A-Z])(?=\s))|((?<=\d)[A-Z])|([A-Z](?=\s))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z])|([A-Z](?=[A-Z]))
```

**EDIT:**

Added one more group due to comment

Explanation:

Group 1: `((^[A-Z])(?=\s))`
Breakdown: Looks for a capital letter at the beginning of a line that is followed by whitespace

Group 2: `((?<=\d)[A-Z])`
Breakdown: Looks for a capital letter that is preceded by a number

Group 3: `([A-Z](?=\s))`
Breakdown: Looks for a capital letter followed by whitespace

Group 4: `((?<=[a-z])[A-Z])`
Breakdown: Looks for a capital letter preceded by a lower-case letter

Group 5: `([A-Z](?=[A-Z]))`
Breakdown: Looks for a capital letter with a capital letter directly after it

Comment: I tested this in Rublar.  Using the December block testing it matched everything except the last C that is right next to the sales figure: Sales $123,000C

Comment: Demo of this in [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jQ7cX5/2) to show functionality.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor try the new pattern -- I'm not sure why the original did not work, but I added in another capture group for capital letters with a digit behind them.

Comment: That did the trick.  regex101 seems to work better than rublar. Thanks.

Comment: Either way, you should probably use the updated pattern, as it will specifically look for digit\cap letter patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `^([ABCDEFGJLMNOPRSTUVY])\s+\1\s*([-a-zA-Z\d, $]+)\1$` and replacing by `\2` should get you close.

Tested on TextWrangler 4.5.11

Slightly adjusted to work on [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/eD6dF0/1)

Adding `^&+` to the second spelled out class seems to fix @Mutuelinvestor Rubular. (Didn't care for it earlier on, as it is missing from the verbatim test data.)

Thus: `^([ABCDEFGJLMNOPRSTUVY])\s+\1\s*([-a-zA-Z\d, $^&+]+)\1$` to be searched for.

However, it still doesn't handle the very last line, on which the initial capital is repeated only once.

Breakdown:
`^` start of line anchor
`([ABCDEFGJLMNOPRSTUVY])` capturing a single capital letter from months' three letter abbreviations - to target the two later repetitions on the line
`\s+` at least one white space character
`\1` backreferencing letter captured at the beginning of the line
`\s*` any number of white space characters (including none)
`([-a-zA-Z\d, $^&+]+)` capturing any of the characters observed in the apparent payload - to be used for the replacement as \2
`\1` another backreference to the first character on the line
`$` end of line anchor

Comment: Would this also capture the capital T in travel or capital O in Operating.  I'm not sure I fully understand your expression.

Comment: If the capital letter doesn't start the line, it will never be hit later on on the line, as the start of line character is being referenced later in the search expression.

Comment: I also tested your solution in Rublar. It excels at matching Ds and Es, but doen't march any of the Cs in the December block:  http://rubular.com/r/SO39pnT994

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Which of it needs more explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure what the \1$ and the \2 do. Otherwise I think I get ti. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Did add some more detail for your reference.